# How do I populate checkboxes in EJS for an edit route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am making my first project as a newbie - just a simple content/property listings app.

I am taking user data from a form and displaying it on a show form. I have a checkbox section and a radio button section - I am using body parser to take the value from those to an array. However, when on the edit page I cannot get the checkboxes to prefill the assigned values.

```
<div class="form-control" id="propertyRoomsForm">
    <div class="form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="livingroom" class="form-check-input" name="propertyRooms[]" value="living room">
        <label for="livingroom" class="form-check-label"> living room</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="kitchen" class="form-check-input" name="propertyRooms[]" value="kitchen">
        <label for="kitchen" class="form-check-label"> kitchen</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="diningroom" class="form-check-input" name="propertyRooms[]" value="dining room">
        <label for="diningroom" class="form-check-label"> dining room</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hall" class="form-check-input" name="propertyRooms[]" value="hall">
        <label for="hall" class="form-check-label"> hall</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The information from the above form is submitted to the edit route as an array = ['living room', 'hall' ...]

```
router.post("/", isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
    const listing = new Property({
        propertyUser: {
            id: req.user._id,
            name: req.user.username
        },
        propertyDescription: req.body.propertyDescription,
        propertyBeds: req.body.propertyBeds,
        propertyImage: req.body.propertyImage,
        propertyLocation: req.body.propertyLocation,
        propertyRooms: req.body.propertyRooms,
        propertyPrice: req.body.propertyPrice,
        propertyType: req.body.propertyType
    });
});
```

I imagine there is something further I need to be doing on the 'new property' form that I am missing an obvious trick. I imagine something to do with onClick() but I can't think how to go about it. Or is there something I need to be adding to my edit form with ejs to populate the data?

Comment: What is serving your ejs file? You'll either need to supply data to it or have a way of requesting it.

Comment: I am passing in "property" which contains all the data gathered from the form from my routes file.

Comment: Then my answer below should be sufficient at solving your problem.

Comment: Took me a minute to get it working then! changed <% ... %> to <%= %>. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, yes sorry, you're right I did forget the =. I could have sworn I had it in there. I'll fix my answer for posterity. If you feel so inclined to mark it as the answer or give it an upvote. :D

Answer (score 1):

If you supply your ejs with a property object then you can conditionally use the checked HTML attribute to check checkboxes if the inputs value is in the propertyRoom array. It should look something like this:

```
<div class="form-control" id="propertyRoomsForm">
    <div class="form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="livingroom" class="form-check-input" name="propertyRooms[]" value="living room" <%= property.propertyRooms.includes("living room") ? "checked" : "" %>>
        <label for="livingroom" class="form-check-label"> living room</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="kitchen" class="form-check-input" name="propertyRooms[]" value="kitchen" <%= property.propertyRooms.includes("kitchen") ? "checked" : "" %>>
        <label for="kitchen" class="form-check-label"> kitchen</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="diningroom" class="form-check-input" name="propertyRooms[]" value="dining room" <%= property.propertyRooms.includes("dining room") ? "checked" : "" %>>
        <label for="diningroom" class="form-check-label"> dining room</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hall" class="form-check-input" name="propertyRooms[]" value="hall" <%= property.propertyRooms.includes("hall") ? "checked" : "" %>>
        <label for="hall" class="form-check-label"> hall</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obligatory disclaimer: I haven't tested this code so it might take a little tinkering but you get the idea.